# Generate SQL UPDATE from Excel CSV file

Tags: sql, bash, csv, shell, awk

I must write updates in a database from a flat file (CSV).  I want to do that in the shell, with tools such as AWK.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat in.csv | sed -e '1d' | awk -F';' -v q=\' '{               # For each line.
    print "DECLARE @v_trmID varchar(16) = " q $1 q
    print "DECLARE @v_trmNom varchar(6) = " q $3 q
    print "DECLARE @v_trmNbrTrav smallint = " $4
    print "IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM trimestre WHERE trmID = @v_trmID AND trmNom = @v_trmNom)"
    print "    BEGIN"
    print "        UPDATE trimestre"
    print "        SET trmNbrTrav = @v_trmNbrTrav"
    print "        WHERE trmID = @v_trmID AND trmNom = @v_trmNom"
    print "    END"
    print "ELSE"
    print "    BEGIN"
    print "        PRINT " q "The script execution FAILED for record " NR " (pfiID " q " + @v_trmID + " q ", trimestre " q " + @v_trmNom + " q ")." q
    print "    END"
    print "go"
    print ""
}'
```

Though, there a 2 things I don't like:

- The way quotes are inserted; it becomes really difficult to follow, even if I choose for the simpler way I found to write quotes inside an AWK string (instead of multiple escape sequences).  Still, not that readable.
- The fact that every SQL line is not readable as is.  Code is not highlighted as SQL.  I'd like to find a "here doc" solution, where I wouldn't have to prefix lines with `printf`.

Do you have any pieces of advice or better ideas on the way to write robust (because more readable / easily modifiable) code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why involve `bash`, `cat`, `sed`, and `awk`, when the whole solution could be done in `awk` alone?  Not only does it simplify the execution, it also reduces your quoting headaches.

In addition, I recommend dropping the `v_` Hungarian prefix.

Here, I've used `printf` instead of `print`, but it's your choice.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = ";" }

NR > 1 {              # Skip the header row
    trmID = $1;
    trmNom = $3;
    trmNbrTrav = $4;

    printf "IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM trimestre WHERE trmID = '%s' AND trmNom = '%s')\n", trmID, trmNom;
    print  "    BEGIN"
    printf "        UPDATE trimestre SET trmNbrTrav = %d WHERE trmID = '%s' AND trmNom = '%s'\n", trmNbrTrav, trmID, trmNom;
    print  "    END"
    print  "ELSE"
    print  "    BEGIN"
    printf "        PRINT 'The script execution FAILED for record %d (pfiID ''%s'', trimestre ''%s'').'\n", NR - 1, trmID, trmNom;
    print  "    END"
    print  "go"
}
```

Note that any `awk`-based technique is susceptible to SQL injection.  Presumably your CSV data isn't hostile.

Personally, I would do it a bit differently, such that the entire operation is atomic:

1. Create a temporary table.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #csv_upload
   ( trmID VARCHAR(16)
   , trmNom VARCHAR(6)
   , trmNbrTrav SMALLINT
   );
   ```
2. Copy all of the CSV data to the temporary table.  You can use `awk` to generate `INSERT` statements or do a [`BULK INSERT #csv_upload FROM 'filename.csv' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', FIRSTROW = 2 )`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).
3. Do a `JOIN` query to verify that every row in the temporary table corresponds to a row in the `trimestre` table.  If not, then report an error before anything gets modified in the `trimestre` table.
4. Perform one single `UPDATE` for the entire batch, preferably within a transaction.

Comment: This code is the most simpler to read... And thanks a lot for your new way to handle the problem at hand!  Did not know about BULK INSERT...

Answer (score 2):

You can turn this into "here doc" solution by using wrapping it in a *process substitution* `<(...)`, like this:

```
awk -f <(cat << "EOF"
{
    ... // awk script, as if in a file
}
EOF
)
```

This way, you can write `'` directly, as if in a `.awk` script file,
because there `'` is no longer an enclosing character.

Note that `cat << "EOF"` is necessary instead of simply `cat << EOF` to avoid variable expansion of `$1`, `$3` and `$4`.

Also, to avoid multiple `print` statements,
you will have to embed newlines with `\n`, and end lines with `\` to continue the same `print` statement on the next line.

Finally, you don't need the `sed -e 1d`, because awk can do this alone, using a `NR > 1` filter. However, to account for the extra line in the input, whenever you use `NR` in the awk script, you would have to change that to `NR - 1`.

Putting the above together, this script is equivalent to yours (produces same output):

```
awk -F';' -f <(cat << "EOF"
NR > 1 {
print "\
DECLARE @v_trmPfiID_fk varchar(16) = '"$1"'\n\
DECLARE @v_trmNom varchar(6) = '"$3"'\n\
DECLARE @v_trmNbrTrav smallint = "$4"\n\
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM trimestre WHERE trmPfiID_fk = @v_trmPfiID_fk AND trmNom = @v_trmNom)\n\
    BEGIN\n\
        UPDATE trimestre\n\
        SET trmNbrTrav = @v_trmNbrTrav\n\
        WHERE trmPfiID_fk = @v_trmPfiID_fk AND trmNom = @v_trmNom\n\
    END\n\
ELSE\n\
    BEGIN\n\
        PRINT 'The script execution FAILED for record " (NR - 1) " (pfiID ' + @v_trmPfiID_fk + ', trimestre ' + @v_trmNom + ').'\n\
    END\n\
go\n\
"
}
EOF
) < in.csv
```